# Nodejs : How to take dimension of pdf pages with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pdf-generation

How to take the `width` and `height` of the `pdf` page using `nodejs` ?

Is it possible to take the file type also?

Here My code for `angularjs`:

```
$scope.demofun = function () {
    var allowedFormats = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'pdf'];
    var unsupportedSizes = false;
    if ($scope.file1[0].size < (5 * 1024 * 1024)) {
        //Here I will check the file size and restrict the file if the size is not satisfy my condition.
        //And I need to allow only A4 size pdf when uploading for that I want to get the dimension of pdf document 
        //but I don't able to get the dimension of pdf for that I write the code like this but it will wont works:

        if (($scope.file1[0].width >= 21 && $scope.file1[0].width <= 22) && ($scope.file1.height >= 29.7 && $scope.file1.height <= 30.7)) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add what you have tried so far

Comment: I didn't tried yet because I thought in angularjs it is possible to take the dimension but now only I realize it's not possible thats why I am tried with node.js is it possible?

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: I posted my code above sir,please check & give me the solution.But that code is for angularjs-@Dipak chavda

Answer (score 8):

There are many packages which provides this like [calipers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/calipers) and [scissors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scissors), But i found [pdf2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json) is simple and doesn't require on other modules. Here's how you can get width and height using pdf2json

```
PDFParser = require("pdf2json");
let pdfParser = new PDFParser();

pdfParser.loadPDF("./your_file_path"); // ex: ./abc.pdf

pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
  width = pdfData.formImage.Width / 4.5; // pdf width
  height = pdfData.formImage.Pages[0].Height / 4.5; // page height

  console.log(`Height : ${height} in inch`)
  console.log(`Width : ${width} in inch`)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please look at this,
  I am sure you will find solution to your problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json#output-format-reference

This npm package will return you all the required details.